# PDO Prepared Statement "Invalid Parameter Number"

Tags: mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm using a function that's been working through my code and I'm slowly now moving from MySQLi to PDO - this function should "simply" take a SQL statement and an array of variables and set up prepared statements, execute it and returns an array with a "success/fail" code and then the lastInsertId.

The function has been working just fine up until now and considering the error I'm getting (and that I'm new to PDO) I wonder where the issue lies.

First, the functions themselves are pretty benign (constants defined elsewhere)

```
function dbConnect(){
    try {
        if(!defined('PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME')){
            debugPrint('Error: PDO unavailable');
            return false;
        }

        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . DB_SERVER . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=UTF8';

        $opt = [
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        ];

        $db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
        return $db;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        debugPrint($e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}


function dbInsert($sql, $param){
    $ret = [];
    if(!$pdo = dbConnect()){
        $ret[] = 1;
        return $ret;
    }

    if(!$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql){
        echo $pdo->errorInfo();
        $ret[] = 1;
        return $ret;
    }

    if(!$stmt->execute($param)){
        echo $pdo->errorInfo();
        $ret[] = 1;
        return $ret;
    } else {
        $ret[] = 0;
        $ret[1] = $pdo->lastInsertId();
        return $ret;
    }
```

I'm working on code that simply checks to see if an email address appears in a table and if it doesn't, inserts it. I do this checking a lot in my app and about 50% of the time the email supplied will be an existing entry.

```
$sql = 'insert into customer (email) select :email from DUAL where not exists (select 1 from customer where email = :email)';
$bind = [':email' => 'user@bogus.org'];
```

This is the neatest approach I've seen thus far, is a single call to the database and uses prepared statements. However, I'm getting the PDO error "Invalid parameter number" and a stack trace error. I've turned on MySQL logging and it appears that the prepare is OK...

```
Prepare   insert into customer (email) select ? from DUAL where not exists (select 1 from customer where email = ?)
```

... so I can only think that it's the binding, which would make sense considering the number of parameter error, but the exception seems to come from the execution:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in {filename}:78
Stack trace:
    #0 {filename}:78: PDOStatement->execute(Array)
    #1 {callingFile(33)}: dbInsert('insert into cus...', Array)
    #2 {main}
        thrown in {filename} on line 78
```

As I'm quite new in the PDO foray and keen to learn, I would like to find out where I should be looking to address this issue.

I'm loving the capability of PDO and I'm hoping that this isn't too much of an issue to address, but at the moment I'm at a loss as to finding out why this error is being thrown.  I did wonder if it's because I'm using "1"

**Note: 1** I know I can make the email unique within the table, but that would mean the $pdo->execute returns as non-zero, making my function return a non-zero (error) which (at least in my mind) isn't strictly true.

**Note: 2** I also know that I could check the table first to see if the email exists and then insert it if it doesn't : however, I'm not sure this is the best way of doing things (and as the code I'm updating currently does this I was of the opinion of making it PDO'ed as well as potentially being cleverer about the SQL calls themselves).

**Note: 3** I've also changed the SQL statement to the following:

```
$sql = 'insert ignore into customer (email) values (:email)';
$bind = [':email' => 'user@bogus.org'];
```

And this is "OK", but then the auto_incremented primary key in the recipient table skips if an existing email is present (again, trying to keep everything clean, simple and logical) and I really don't want to hack this by appending a (slow) statement altering the table to set auto_increment to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In your function `dbInsert` you missed the last parenthesis of the `if` statement:

```
if (!$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {...}
```

---

2) As stated in the official documentation for [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-description):

> You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than
>   once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.

E.g. You are not allowed to use `:email` more than once in the sql statement, unless you activate the `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` option:

```
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => TRUE
```

If you don't, you receive exactly the error that you've presented.

So, either apply the suggestion from above, or let emulation untouched (e.g. to `FALSE`) and use two different named parameter markers (`:email1` and `:email2`):

```
$email = 'user@bogus.org';

$sql = 'insert into customer (email) select :email1 from DUAL where not exists (select 1 from customer where email = :email2)';

$bind = [
    ':email1' => $email,
    ':email2' => $email,
];
```

Or you could use question mark (?) parameter markers:

```
$email = 'user@bogus.org';

$sql = 'insert into customer (email) select ? from DUAL where not exists (select 1 from customer where email = ?)';

$bind = [
    1 => $email,
    2 => $email,
];
```

As a very good resource I recommend you [this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation) tutorial.

Comment: Argh! I was hoping that it was something simple that my inexperience was falling foul of. Many thanks for the assistance.

Comment: You are welcome. Please pay attention to the fact that the parameter markers should be used only in certain places inside an sql statement. If they are not used where they should, sql injection can not be avoided without effort, or at all. As I recall, the tutorial points out this problem too.

Comment: Permit me to ask: I have things set up (dbInsert calling dbConnect) prevents me from using PDO transactions, correct? I have a file that performs an insert, a select, an insert and finally a last select, and that file wants to ensure everything works, it's that file that should spawn the $pdo->beginTransaction() and ultimately the $pso->commit(), yes? Of course, at the moment it doesn't have a $pdo object as that's being called within the initial dbInsert, so my thought of having dbConnect called within the function needs to be removed, and called from the file itself?

Comment: @bnoeafk Well, I never worked with transactions. But you definitely shouldn't create a db connection, e.g. a pdo object, each time when you are performing a db operation (CRUD). Instead, you should create only one db connection object, which should be shared by all functions and classes that need it. E.g. this one pdo object should be injected as argument in functions, or in class constructors, or used as it is when it comes to vanilla code pieces. In your case, as you already correctly suggested, you should call `dbConnect` separated from any function. So, I would do like this:

Comment: @bnoeafk I would create a php file (`connection.php`) and a new pdo object in it (`$pdo` if you wish), without using any function for this. Just the _try-catch_ block from `dbConnect`. And actually you don't need such exception handling, e.g. _try-catch_ blocks, for such operations at all. Read [this](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) and [this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) to see why and how. Then I would just include the file `connection.php` in all files that require db operations, e.g. a db connection.

Comment: @bnoeafk In your case in the file where all the transaction ops are taking place (`$pdo->beginTransaction()`, I1, S1, I2, S2, `$pdo->commit()`). This way you could easily pass the `$pdo` instance as argument to all the functions implicated in the transaction. Also, please note that you should use `require` or `include`, not `require_once` or `include_once` for including `connection.php`. At last, look at [General purpose query function](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes). Good luck.

Comment: I appreciate the time you've taken in responding and furthermore confirming that the way forward would be to pass the connection object as a parameter, at least I'm not going mad. However, kudos for mentioning the require vs require_once ... I had *not* thought of that and I know I would've fallen foul of it, so thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @bnoeafk ;-) There are "_dependency injection_" and "_dependency inversion_" in OOP. Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ojsn11XY0X8&feature=youtu.be) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) out. So, you must avoid tight coupling in your classes design. E.g. don't create an object inside of a class, but pass it as dependency (e.g. as constructor or setter argument). Also, as a little (but important) note: the **variables** defined in a function definition are called "_parameters_". The **values** passed when the function is called are named "_arguments_".

Comment: @bnoeafk Parameters: `function sum($a, $b){...}`. Arguments: `$mysum = sum(10, 23);`. Bye and have fun.